# pd.read_html - No Tables Found Error - aiohttp refactor from request

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, aiohttp

Okay so I am using yahoo_fin in python however the requests were too slow for my short term use case (pre-redis/cron) and I need an implementation that can make many requests to yahoo finance.

I had converted the code from request to aiohttp/asyncio and despite being awaiting I now get the error **No Tables Found** on some of the requests -- it varies? Did I not implement the async correctly or am I forced to use selenium? (It's ~10x Faster Now fwiw)

BEFORE

```py
 tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(site, headers=headers).text)
```

AFTER

```py
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(site, headers=headers) as resp:
            text = await resp.text()
            tables = pd.read_html(text)
```

I call the AFTER code like so... (small excerpts to illustrate)

```py
async def get_ranking(arr, expiration, optionType, symbol):
    try:
        print(symbol, flush=True)
        price = await async_get_live_price(symbol)
        chain = await async_get_options_chain(symbol, expiration)
```

```py
async with ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*[get_ranking(arr, expiration, optionType, symbol) for symbol in symbols])
```